# Retrofit + SimpleXMLConverter works on Lollipop and not on Kitkat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, retrofit, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an app that was working fine. However when I started using CompileSDKVersion 23 (I moved up from 22 because the Toolbar was not displaying in Lollipop). Now it works on Lollipop devices, but crashes when I run on Kitkat.

The error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.converter.SimpleXMLConverter
        at com.app.appname.api.AppAPI.<init>(AppAPI.java:80)
        at com.app.appname.api.AppAPI.getInstance(AppAPI.java:95)
        at com.app.appname.broker.DataBroker.<init>(DataBroker.java:31)
        at com.app.appname.broker.DataBroker.init(DataBroker.java:35)
        at com.app.appname.AppApplication.onCreate(AppApplication.java:18)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am trying to initialise a Retrofit API:

```
mAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(...)
            .setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter())
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
```

My Gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0'){
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:1.2.1@aar'
}
```

I have tried:

1. Adding JCenter() to the repo's
2. Including GSon libraries
3. Moving all the activities to a single package and setting the package name in the manifest
4. Finding about annotations (I can't find it under Preferences -> Build -> Compiler)
5. Deploying to a different device with the same API level (4.2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a nearly identical setup to yours, including:

Retrofit 1.9.0
SimpleXMLConverter 1.9.0
compileSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion 23.0.1

And my application works fine, all the way down to API level 16 (my minimum).

The main differences i can see that could cause issues are:

1) Excluding stax, stax-api and xpp3 from SimpleXMLConverter. I remember messing around with excluding those as well when i started using it, as i had some issues, but i no longer need to exclude them, maybe try removing the excludes and see?

2) Inluding Okhttp-urlconnection. I know Retrofit will automatically use that if it's included, might cause issues (just a guess).

3) Multidex enabled. I haven't messed around with this myself, but i have read issues with it here on StackOverflow, if possible, try disabling it and see? Might be better to enable minify instead of running multidex, to remove some of the unneeded functions.

Comment: Great stuff thank you! I thought I was the only one on the planet still using REST + XML! I just needed to follow steps 2 + 3 (My project will not build without step 1) - I really appreciate your answer!